# Where to define a filter function for a form field in my Joomla component's preferences

Tags: joomla, filter, components, preferences

I am creating a component in Joomla 2.5. This component has some options that are defined in its **config.xml**, so they can be set in the preferences of the component. Now I would like to apply a filter to one of these option fields, using the attribute `filter="my_filter"`.

In the source code of JForm I saw the following lines at the very end of the implementation of `JForm::filterField()`:

```
if (strpos($filter, '::') !== false && is_callable(explode('::', $filter)))
{
  $return = call_user_func(explode('::', $filter), $value);
}
elseif (function_exists($filter))
{
  $return = call_user_func($filter, $value);
}
```

That's what I needed for using a filter function defined by myself!

I managed to do this for form fields used in the views of my component. I defined the filter function as `MyComponentHelper::my_filter()`, where `MyComponentHelper` is a helper class which I always load in the very base of my component. And in the form's xml I added `filter="MyComponentHelper::my_filter"` to the fields that have to be filtered. However... when I am trying to apply the filter function to a form field in my component's preferences, I am not in my own component, but in **com_config** instead, so my helper class is not available!

So, therefore, my question: where to define my own filter function in such a way that it can be found and called by `JForm::filterField()` in **com_config**?? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In the meantime I came up with a (quite big) work around/solution. I liked the way validation can use classes extended from JFormRule, but filtering does not have that implemented. So I extended the classes JForm and ConfigControllerComponent and ConfigModelComponent (part of com_config) and now they can use classes extended from a JFormFilter class exactly the same way as validation is implemented!

Comment: I had the same feeling with Joomla Extension API. It took more time to implement the features I needed than implementing the actual application... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it is too late, but this topic is only I found about that trouble. May be my solution will be helpfull to someone.
1) Add to tag  of .xml form file the attribute 'addfieldpath' like this:

```
<fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="PATH_TO_MY_EXTENSION/models/fields">
```

2) Modify filtered field description like this:

```
<field
    name="MY_FIELD_NAME"
    type="myfildtype"
    label="MY_FIELD_LABEL"
    description="MY_FIELD_DESC"
    filter="JFormFieldMyFieldType::filter"
/>
```

3) Create the file 'PATH_TO_MY_EXTENSION/models/fields/myfildtype.php':

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('text'); // or other standard Joomla! field type

class JFormFieldMyFieldType extends JFormFieldText // or other standard Joomla! field type class
{
    protected $type = 'MyFieldType';

    public static function filter($value)
    {
        // filter code
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice and clean way! Didn't think of that... Too late for me, but for sure worth posting it for others.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with the same issue today. Here is what I did.

> Our form field looks like this:
>
> ```
> <field name="verwaltungskosten" type="text" class="form-control" size="40" label="Verwaltungskosten" labelclass="col-sm-2
> ```
>
> compojoom-control-label"
>         filter="MyComponentFilterDouble::filter" required="true"/>
>
> As you can see we have a filter. We've specified
>   MyComponentFilterDouble as class and filter as a method of this class.
>   If you have a look at libraries/joomla/form/form.php in the
>   FilterField function toward the end you'll see that the code will try
>   to execute our custom filter. Now here comes the tricky part. How does
>   Joomla know where our filters are located? Well, it doesn't! We have
>   to load our filters in advance. JForm doesn't come with a utility
>   class that could load a custom filter. I've decided to load our
>   Filters in our model in the getForm function. As you know each model
>   that extends from JModelAdmin should have a getForm function. This
>   function makes sure that we are loading the correct form from a .xml
>   file. So in this function just before I load the form I did:
>
> ```
> JLoader::discover('MyComponentFilter', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_mycomponent/models/forms/filters');
> ```
>
> The discover method will make sure to auto load our class when we need
>   it. This way it will be available to our form.
>
> And there we go! Now when our model validates the form. It actually
>   always first performs filtering on the data. Now in our custom filter
>   we can modify the data and pass it back for validation. It's that
>   easy!

The above text is in quotes because I took it from my blogpost about that same issue over here: https://compojoom.com/blog/entry/custom-filtering-for-jform-fields

Comment: This is what I meant with "I managed to do this for form fields used in the views* of my component." *models/forms

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is actually adding custom validation to one of your form fields.  If that's the case you actually need to be looking at [adding server-side validation](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_verifications) in addition to [adding configuration](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_configuration).  Pay particular attention to the 'addrulepath' in the example under the heading "Using configuration parameters as default value".  You'll most likely end up extending JFormRule, of which I've included a very stripped-down example below.

```
<?php
/** headers */
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die; // Joomla only

class JFormRuleCustom extends JFormRule
{
    public $type = 'Custom';

    public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null) {
        return /* true for passed validation, false for failed validation */
    }
}
```

When you've got that down you can add the validation "custom" to your form fields like so:

```
<field
    name="pw1"
    type="password"
    label="COM_NEWUSER_UPDATE_LABEL_PASSWORD1"
    description="COM_NEWUSER_UPDATE_DESCRIPTION_PASSWORD1"
    message="COM_NEWUSER_UPDATE_ERROR_PASSWORD1"
    size="40"
    required="true"
    validate="custom"
    minlength="5"
    maxlength="20"
    specials="!@#$%^&amp;*"
/>
```

Hopefully that answers your question and didn't go totally off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. As far as I know, validation can not change the input value. It can only abort saving the form on invalid input and show a message. What I needed is the ability of filtering, which can change/convert the actual input to a desired form. However, I liked the way validation uses classes extended from JFormRule, but filtering does not have that implemented. In the meantime I already extended com_config and class JForm and now they use extended JFormFilter classes exactly the same way as validation does, but now for filtering, able to change the input value!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get what you were looking for, but I'm glad it help at least.